# How to enable Google Play Games on PC option for published google play games

Tags: forms, unity-game-engine, console, find, solution

I have many android games on google play store ( google developer console ) .
What i am trying to do is no enable Google Play Games on PC for my games , i already implement keyboard inputs and game  working fine on pc .
All What i need is to allow  Google Play Games on PC form factor .

see image 1 [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKnfp.jpg)

this include the instructions for allowing  Google Play Games on PC

but when i try this i can not find this option at all .

google instructions:
""""""""
to enable the Google Play Games on PC form factor:

1 -Go to advanced distribution settings at Release > Advanced settings (direct link)

## 2 -Go to the Form factors tab and add Google Play Games on PC from the + Add form factor dropdown.

""""

i can not find step two .

the available options are :
Android Tv
Wear OS
Android Automotive
Android Auto play
Google Play Instant

## Can not find

## Google Play Games on PC

see image 2 [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcJRe.jpg)

Please Help .

I need a solution for this issue .